# how do I make jenkins/hudson complain on 1 failing test out of 500?

Tags: unit-testing, hudson, jenkins

I am developer for a couple of libraries, [csvjdbc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/) on sourceforge, [logging](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/logging/) on r-forge, and I'm using jenkins/hudson to keep track of their status.

I'd like to set the threshold for the bright shining sun on unit tests to 1.  now it is somewhere above 3%.

I don't find the place where I can set thresholds.

Comment: What unit-testing/plugins are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settled with the current behaviour: if at least one test is failing, the "green ball" left of the "bright shining sun" becomes yellow.  once I realize a yellow ball next to a shining sun is worse than a green ball next to a cloudy sky, it makes sense.